# How to Debug a C code that is compiled using a Makefile

Tags: c, debugging

I am asked to debug a C code containing a number of .c files and is complied using a Makefile on a Redhat Linux system. I want to debug that whole code. How to go about it? What changes do i need to make in the Makefile?

I am using gcc as the compiler.

Comment: What tool chain are you using? You'll need to add "debug" flags to your compiler and linker commands, but those vary between tools.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the build environment (Mac, Win, Linux, etc) and the tools you're using (vc compiler, gnu, etc).

Comment: Added the necessary information in the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using GCC as compiler add to the `CFLAGS` variable the `-g` option. Then you'll be able to debug the resulting executable using the `gdb` command.

Comment: ``-ggdb`` would provide more debug information, but is gdb specific. If you use gdb it is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add the flag "-g" during compilation(make this change in the makefile.if already present then no need). this will open up the symbols for debugging the code.

use the debugging tools available like gdb, dbx, mdb which ever is available in your system.

many resources are available for debugging. one of them is [here](http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/DebugCPP/Volume/debug.html)

Comment: So u mean that after adding -g option and compiling the code, I run: gdb program-name program-arguments to start debugging?

Comment: Yes...after you generate the binary...you can start it with bebugger.

Comment: I have added the debugging option in the makefile as:

CFLAGS=-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -g.

However, when i start debugging using:

gdb <executable-name>, it gives me following as output:

(no debugging symbols found)...done.

Any clue what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: I guess you have not given the complete path of the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Add -g option in your makefile in order to invoke gdb debugger in the future.The way you debug on gdb is like : gdb yourprogram,then you will be redirected to another interface.type "run yourarguments" to start off debugging